# words meaning the rest / reminder/ remains

Tags: word-usage, word-meaning

I am trying to say that something has not change for a period of specific time.

> rest / reminder/ remains

I know the meaning of each word but to me as non-native speaker these words mean the same thing. What I am trying to convey is something has not change throughout the night

> Client slept with no issues for rest/ rest / reminder/ remains of the night.

If non of them works what you suggest?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's *remainder*, not *reminder*, and all three words need *the* in front.

*The rest of the night* is probably the most idiomatic. Although there is a famous novel called *The Remains of the Day*, I would say that *remains* is the least idiomatic in this sense, as it usually refers to something physical, such as leftovers from a meal or a dead body ('mortal remains').

Comment: My first thought was that of the remaining terms (after discarding ***remains***, as you concisely justify), ***the remainder of the day*** sounded relatively unlikely compared to ***rest***. I thought [this NGram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=the+rest+of+the+time%2Cthe+remainder+of+the+time&year_start=1790&year_end=2019&corpus=28&smoothing=10&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cthe%20rest%20of%20the%20time%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cthe%20remainder%20of%20the%20time%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cthe%20rest%20of%20the%20time%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cthe%20remainder%20of%20the%20time%3B%2Cc0) was interesting..

Comment: ... it shows that a century or two ago, ***the remainder of the time*** was at least as common as ***the rest of the time***, but in the last few decades that latter version has become completely dominant.

Comment: @kate thanks for your answer. Should I edit the word remainder, not reminder in my post before accepting the answer?

Comment: You can if you want (but I will then have to edit my answer!)